# What's the word for a word with a similar spelling to another word?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that qualifies a word as having a similar spelling to another word? Let's consider the following example:

> Affect is a ___ to effect.

I know homonyms are used to identify words that have similar sounds, but it's not used to identify words with similar spelling.

Answer (score 1):

A **homophone** is a word that sounds the same as another word, but is spelled differently.  Examples are *dear* and *deer*, *stake* and *steak*, and many others.